# If S is an infinite set and R is a well-ordering on S, then R has an initial segment isomorphic to ω.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know the above fact, but do not know how to prove it rogorously. Does it follow from the fact that two well-orders are isomorphic to each other or one of them is isomorphic to initial segment of the other?

Comment: Explaining Andres' edit: the "set-theory" tag is used for more advanced topics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can identify the order type of $R$ with some infinite ordinal. Let's call this ordinal $\gamma$.

Now, because the class of ordinals is itself well-ordered by $\in$, exactly one of the following must be true:

$(1)\quad\gamma\in \omega$

$(2)\quad\gamma=\omega$

$(3)\quad \gamma\ni\omega$

If $(1)$ were true, then $S$ would be finite, since $\omega$ contains only finite ordinals.

If $(2)$ is true, then $R$ is order-isomorphic to $\omega$.

If $(3)$ is true $\gamma$ is larger than $\omega$ (at least $\omega+1$).

From here, it is easy to show that $\omega$ is an initial segment of $\gamma$.